# Drupal 8 and stylesheets

Tags: drupal, stylesheet

Drupal 8 won't render my stylesheet. Any ideas why it won't render?

I've tried clearing the cache but that didn't help. below is my code:

fluffiness.info.yml

```
name: fluffiness
type: theme
description: "A cuddly theme that offers extra fluffiness"
core: 8.x
libraries:
  -fluffiness/cuddly-slider
base them: classy
regions:
  header: Header
  content: Content
  sidebar_first: 'Sidebar first'
  footer: Footer
```

fluffiness.libraries.yml

```
cuddly-slider:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/cuddly-slider.css: {}
  js:
    js/cuddly-slider.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

themes/custom/fluffiness/page--front.html.twig

```
{{ attach_library('fluffiness/cuddly-slider') }}
<header role="banner">
    {{ page.header }}
</header>
<div class="layout-container">

  <main role="main">
    <a id="main-s" tabindex="-1"></a>{# link is in html.html.twig #}

    <div class="layout-content">
      {{ page.content }}
    </div>{# /.layout-content #}


  </main>

  {% if page.footer %}
    <footer role="contentinfo">
      {{ page.footer }}
    </footer>
  {% endif %}

</div>
```

themes/custom/fluffiness/css/cuddly-slider.css

```
header {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: I discovered that my stylesheet works when I logout, but when I'm logged in it doesn't work

Comment: Symptoms are suggesting that when you are not logged in content is served from cache and that's the reason why it works. But you said you tried clearing the cache so it makes no much sense. Are you sure that you cleared cache well?

Comment: Yes, I went to configuration, performance, clear all caches

Comment: In Configuration > Development > Performance uncheck the option for 'Aggregate CSS files' then flush cache